# Failed to get data in another child from prom parent process in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

If I declare a Queue object global level and I don't pass it to a target function in multiprocessing and  put some data in Queue object and not able to get in main thread . When my Process is calling get method in Queue object, it is in continuous loop as it is waiting for some data in Queue object.

```
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
    
    def getretsults(*kwargs):
        print("Executing Get Results..........")
        res = []
        for i in kwargs[0]:
            res.append(i**i)
        if len(kwargs) >= 1:
            q = kwargs[1]
        print(f"{id(q) = }")
        q.put(res)
    
    
    q = Queue()
    
    
    def main_process():
        a =256
        b = 900
        print("Executing Main Process.........")
        args = [
            range(1,6),
            range(6,11),
            range(11,16)
        ]
    
        print(f"{id(args) = }")
    
        process_ = []
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            q = Queue()
            for x in args:
                p = Process(target=getretsults, args=(x,))
                process_.append(p)
                p.start()
    
            for x_ in process_:
                x_.join()
    
    
            print(q.get())
    
    main_process()
```

Comment: What is your OS you are running under (you should be tagging your question with the OS)?

Answer (score 0):

I asked what OS you were running under and have not received a response. I will initially assume it is a platform that uses the *fork* method to create child processes (such as Linux). I will present a second version that will work under Linux or Windows.

You have several issues with your code, some minor some major.

1. The name of your argument to `getresults` is *kwargs* and represents an iterable (tuple) of all the positional parameters being passed. It's a minor point (and not anything that is causing an error), but the convention is to name this argument *args* and to use the name *kwargs* to receive keyword parameters.
2. If you are running under an OS that uses *fork* to create new processes, then you can declare `q` to be global and the child processes will inherit a reference to this queue instance. You can also, instead, create a queue as a non-global and pass it as an argument. But in `main_process` you have `q = Queue()` and you did not declare `q` global. This results in creating a new *local* variable `q` and is not assigning this new queue instance to the global `q` variable. Therefore, the `q` on which results are being put is not the same `q` that the main process is getting from. This is a major bug.
3. You must never `join` a child process that is putting elements on a multiprocessing queue before you have retrieved all the elements with `get`. Otherwise, you can hang because the child process often cannot terminate until these elements have been retrieved.
4. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `print(f"{id(args) = }")`. If you are trying to print the id, then perhaps `print(f"id(args} = {id(args)}")`.
5. In `getresults` your test `if len(kwargs) >= 1:` should be `if len(kwargs) > 1:`.
6. In `getresults` depending on whether a queue instance has been passed as the second argument or not should determine whether you will put your results to the passed queue argument or the global queue that has been declared.
7. If you are running under Windows or any platform that uses the *spawn* method to create child processes, you must pass the queue instance as a parameter. This is because each child process will be re-executing the `q = Queue()`, which is at the global level, and therefore will definitely each be  putting to different queues from one another and from which the main process is doing gets against.

With these corrections we end up with:

**Linux-only Version**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

q = Queue()

def getretsults(*args):
    print("Executing Get Results..........")
    res = []
    for i in args[0]:
        res.append(i**i)
    if len(args) > 1: # Must be >, not >=
        result_q = args[1]
    else:
        result_q = q # global q
    print(f'id(result_q) = {id(result_q)}')
    result_q.put(res)


def main_process():
    global q

    a =256
    b = 900
    print("Executing Main Process.........")
    args = [
        range(1,6),
        range(6,11),
        range(11,16)
    ]

    print(f"id(args) = {id(args)}")

    process_ = []
    q = Queue()
    for x in args:
        p = Process(target=getretsults, args=(x,))
        process_.append(p)
        p.start()

    for _ in range(len(args)):
        print(q.get())

    for x_ in process_:
        x_.join()

main_process()
```

Prints:

```None
Executing Main Process.........
id(args) = 140481897185024
Executing Get Results..........
id(result_q) = 140481897250768
Executing Get Results..........
id(result_q) = 140481897250768
Executing Get Results..........
id(result_q) = 140481897250768
[1, 4, 27, 256, 3125]
[285311670611, 8916100448256, 302875106592253, 11112006825558016, 437893890380859375]
[46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 10000000000]
```

**OS-independent Version**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def getretsults(x, q):
    print("Executing Get Results..........")
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.append(i**i)
    print(f'id(q) = {id(q)}')
    q.put(res)


def main_process():
    a =256
    b = 900
    print("Executing Main Process.........")
    args = [
        range(1,6),
        range(6,11),
        range(11,16)
    ]

    print(f"id(args) = {id(args)}")

    process_ = []
    q = Queue()
    for x in args:
        p = Process(target=getretsults, args=(x, q))
        process_.append(p)
        p.start()

    for _ in range(len(args)):
        print(q.get())

    for x_ in process_:
        x_.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_process()
```

Prints:

```None
Executing Main Process.........
id(args) = 1775036479808
Executing Get Results..........
id(q) = 2365890922528
Executing Get Results..........
id(q) = 2128150562848
Executing Get Results..........
id(q) = 2368897255456
[46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 10000000000]
[285311670611, 8916100448256, 302875106592253, 11112006825558016, 437893890380859375]
[1, 4, 27, 256, 3125]
```

**Note that the id of the queue is different for each child process and that the order that results are put on the queue by the child processes is different and cannot be depended on using explicit `Process` instances putting to a queue.**

**Version Using a Multiprocessing Pool**

Here we can guarantee the order in which results are returned (note that I am including some code improvements):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Renamed worker function:
def getresults(x):
    print("Executing Get Results..........", flush=True)
    return [i ** i for i in x] # More efficiently expressed!


def main_process():
    print("Executing Main Process.........", flush=True)
    args = [
        range(1,6),
        range(6,11),
        range(11,16)
    ]

    with Pool(3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(getresults, args)
    for result in results:
        print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_process()
```

Prints:

```
Executing Main Process.........
Executing Get Results..........
Executing Get Results..........
Executing Get Results..........
[1, 4, 27, 256, 3125]
[46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 10000000000]
[285311670611, 8916100448256, 302875106592253, 11112006825558016, 437893890380859375]
```